# purpose of read rev in this bash oneliner

Tags: git, bash, shell

So, the following bash oneliner will generate similar output as `git log`

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD | while read rev; do git log -1 $rev; done
```

What I want to know is, what is the purpose of `read rev` in this context? Is there another way this could be written without `read rev` perhapse with `xargs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use xargs in this case:

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD | xargs -L 1 -J % git log -1 %
```

To explain how `read rev` works here, the loop reads one line from its input (in this case, from the output of the `git rev-list --reverse HEAD` command) and stores it in the variable `rev`.  Then, any commands within the loop can use the variable `rev`.  As an example:

```
seq 1 5 | while read x; do echo "value is $x"; done
```

will show

```
value is 1
value is 2
value is 3
value is 4
value is 5
```

Comment: The `-J %` is not POSIX standard.  I believe you could omit that option and the `%` at the end and achieve a more portable result.  I also believe `-L <n>` is relatively new in POSIX; some OS may not support that yet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler every `xargs` I worked with had both options, which is why I kinda presumed it was standard.

Comment: Awesome! But what I really am curious about is how read rev is bringing in the data from the pipe. I dont get how reversing anything is helping here. :(

Comment: @BeMathis your original question was " Is there another way this could be written without read rev perhapse with xargs", for which I presented the solution.  As far as the other question is concerned, I updated the response

Comment: A quick poll suggests: 5 main Unix platforms support `-L` (Solaris 10, HP-UX 11.23, AIX 6, Linux, MacOS X); of these, only Linux and MacOS X also support `-J`.

Comment: @BeMathis: the `rev` in the script is a variable name, not a command name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for looking into that.  Do you have links?  It would be nice to see a comparison

Comment: @Foo Bah: I looked around the 5 main 'species' of Unix-like machine we work on at the office, running 'man xargs' on each.  I don't have URLs to share - sorry.